# Match row with other rows

Tags: excel

I am having a challenge with an Excel formula. I have 2 sheets each containing a list of rows.

Sheet 1:

```
Company name         -        Profession
Joes Carpentry                Carpenter
Peters Brick                  Bricklayer
Ross' service                 Damageservice
```

Sheet 2:

```
Company name         -        Profession
Joes Carpentry                Carpenter
Peters Brick                  Carpenter
Ross' service                 Damageservice
```

I need to formula to check if the profession of the company has changed so a result should look like this:

Sheet 1:

```
Company name         -        Profession          
Joes Carpentry                Carpenter             False
Peters Brick                  Bricklayer            True
Ross' service                 Damageservice         False
```

I have tried using and if statement and set up 2 VLOOKUPs against each other, but it gave the wrong results. Here is what i did before

I created 2 VLOOKUPS one that checks Sheet1 and one that checks Sheet2:

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A2;Sheet1!A2:C2;3;FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A2;Sheet2!A2:C140;3;FALSE)
```

Now i do a check that matches these two results:

```
=IF(Sheet1!E2=F2;0;1)
```

Even though results are equal it sometimes outputs wrong result

i.e.

```
Column E              Column F            Column G
   1                     1                   1
```

How can this be?

Comment: Please, provide formula you already tried.

Comment: If you put this formula in cell C2, & drag down does it work?

=IF(B2=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A1:B4,2),FALSE,TRUE)

Comment: Hi Tony

It actually does the same as my calculations. Even though some results are matching, the if statements shows wrong.

like =IF(1=1;true;false)  output = false

Why is this?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me why =IF(1=1,TRUE,FALSE) would produce FALSE for an output. Seems pretty fundamental, and it certainly produces TRUE for me.  Perhaps someone else would know.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to trim your strings containing professions in both sheets and used them. Then use two VLOOKUPS as before and use and IF statement to compare. That will work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data set above, presuming that the first column is A, and the second column is B, I was able to accomplish this with the following formula (in C2 of sheet 1, copy in and drag down):

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$3,2,FALSE)=Sheet1!B2,FALSE,TRUE)
```

Keep in mind that the Sheet2!$A$1:$B$3 will need to be changed to cover the actual size of your data set.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose:

```
Company name (sheet1 A1)        -        Profession (sheet1 C1)
Joes Carpentry (sheet1 A2)               Carpenter  (sheet1 C2)
Peters Brick (sheet1 A3)                 Bricklayer  (sheet1 C3)
Ross' service (sheet1 A4                 Damageservice  (sheet1 C4)
```

And the same for sheet2 with your other table.

then use in sheet 1 E2 (and copy through to the end):

```
    =IF(C2=VLOOKUP(A2,sheet2!A:C,3,FALSE),"true","false")
```

You could add conditional formatting to color your "false" red:

1. Select column E in sheet1 (where the true/false statements are)
2. Click conditional formatting on the "start" tab in Excel
3. Pick "Highlight cells rules" > "Text that contains..."
4. Type in "false" and click OK

see this for reference: http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/conditional-formatting.html